# Problema con Diccionarios

Tags: python

Quiero hacer la siguiente consulta:

Estoy creando un diccionario a partir de datos que provienen desde un CSV.
Tengo una key que tiene diferentes values, entonces agregué esta línea de código buscando que, si existe anteriormente ese ID en el diccionario, agregue esos values a esa key. Si no existe, crea los values.

```
if id_partida in datos_partidas:
    datos_partidas[id_partida]+=[id_subtitulo,nombre_subtitulo,monto_original,monto_a_marzo,moneda]
else:
    datos_partidas[id_partida]=[id_subtitulo,nombre_subtitulo,monto_original,monto_a_marzo,moneda]
```

El problema es que el output generado es algo así:

```
{'01': ['08',
  'OTROS INGRESOS CORRIENTES',
  311948.0,
  311948.0,
  'CLP',
  '09',
  'APORTE FISCAL',
  18414647.0,
  18536395.0,
  'CLP',
  '10',
  'VENTA DE ACTIVOS NO FINANCIEROS',
  16929.0,
  16929.0,
  'CLP',
  '15',
  'SALDO INICIAL DE CAJA',
  1000.0,
  842590.0,
  'CLP',
  '21',
  'GASTOS EN PERSONAL',
  8189139.0,
  8189139.0,
  'CLP']
```

Y lo que yo necesito es que me quede algo así:

```
{'01': {'08',
  'OTROS INGRESOS CORRIENTES',
  311948.0,
  311948.0,
  'CLP'},
  {'09',
  'APORTE FISCAL',
  18414647.0,
  18536395.0,
  'CLP'},
  {'10',
  'VENTA DE ACTIVOS NO FINANCIEROS',
  16929.0,
  16929.0,
  'CLP'},
  {'15',
  'SALDO INICIAL DE CAJA',
  1000.0,
  842590.0,
  'CLP'},
  {'21',
  'GASTOS EN PERSONAL',
  8189139.0,
  8189139.0,
  'CLP'}
```

Cómo podría crear ese diccionario anidado, por así decirlo?

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La salida que solicitas no es un diccionario anidado, debido a que algo como por ejemplo:

```
{'08',
  'OTROS INGRESOS CORRIENTES',
  311948.0,
  311948.0,
  'CLP'},
```

no es un diccionario, ya que no tiene la estructura clave-valor. El hecho de que tenga llaves alrededor podría hacer pensar que se trata de un conjunto (`set()`) que es un tipo de datos Python que también usa llaves para delimitarse. Pero los conjuntos no admiten elementos repetidos, y el que se muestra sí que tiene datos repetidos como el `311948.0`

Entiendo que has puesto llaves sin saber muy bien por qué, pero que en el fondo te valdría tener sub-listas, delimitadas por `[,]`. Es decir, que lo que buscas es que en la clave `"01":` del diccionario haya una lista, cuyos elementos serían sub-listas. Como lo siguiente:

```
{'01': [  # Inicio de la lista de sub-listas
  ['08',
   'OTROS INGRESOS CORRIENTES',
   311948.0,
   311948.0,
   'CLP'],
  ['09',
   'APORTE FISCAL',
   18414647.0,
   18536395.0,
   'CLP'],
  ['10',
   'VENTA DE ACTIVOS NO FINANCIEROS',
   16929.0,
   16929.0,
   'CLP'],
  ['15',
   'SALDO INICIAL DE CAJA',
   1000.0,
   842590.0,
   'CLP'],
  ['21',
   'GASTOS EN PERSONAL',
   8189139.0,
   8189139.0,
   'CLP']
  ],  # Fin de la lista de sub-listas

# Aqui iría otra clave, etc...

} # Fin del diccionario
```

En este caso el código necesario para generar lo anterior sería algo así (no puedo testearlo al no tener tus datos, pero debería funcionar):

```
for ... # algún tipo de bucle
  if id_partida not in datos_partidas:
      datos_partidas[id_partida] = []   # Lista vacía
  # Después agregamos la nueva sublista a la lista
  datos_partidas[id_partida].append(
        [id_subtitulo, nombre_subtitulo, monto_original, monto_a_marzo,moneda])
```

Comment: Eso era lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias Abulafia!

Comment: Una pregunta @Abulafia, sabes como podría hacer para que el output del código qe me enviaste pudiera salir de esta forma:

  [{Subtitulo:'21',
   'Nombre subtitulo': 'GASTOS EN PERSONAL',
   'Monto original': 8189139.0,
   'Monto a marzo': 8189139.0,
   'Moneda':'CLP']
  ]

Comment: Claro, basta que dentro del `.append()` pongas el diccionario que te interese: `.append({'Subtitulo': id_subtitulo, 'Nombre subtitulo': nombre_subtitulo, 'Monto original': monto_original, 'Monto a marzo': monto_a_marzo, 'Moneda': moneda})`